# Reconstructing joint distribution from marginals

Tags: modeling, joint-distribution, maximum-entropy

I think this is a rather open question. Suppose I have bi-dimensional data $(x_i, y_i)$. I have some reasonable model for the marginals, say distributions $F_X$ and $F_Y$ (parametric).

How to reasonably construct a bi-dimensional model for the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ that respects say,  the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ or some other higher moment? Of course I'm not considering normal variates.

Comment: Are you familiar with [tag:copula]s?

Comment: The bidimensional data that you have _are_ a model for the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$, and the corresponding sample marginal distributions are a model for the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$. Incidentally, you say that you are not considering normal variates but even if you are, estimating a joint normal distribution from the sample correlation is also model-building where you have rejected all other joint distributions in favor of the joint normal, even though, as [cardinal points out](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30205/6633), this is the exception and not the rule.

Comment: Some people would approach this as finding the max-ent joint distribution with the given marginals and the given correlation (and maybe some other stats). See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.0440.pdf  and  http://yaroslavvb.com/papers/abbas-entropy.pdf