# Derivation of the Bivariate normal distribution using change-of-variable technique

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis

[image]

I am not familiar with the change-of-variable technique that the question refers to. Does anyone have an idea what is meant and how one should go about doing it?

Comment: Note: this is not a homework question, but I'm studying for exams.

Comment: Most likely by `the change-of-variables technique` is meant the usual method involving Jacobians. However, the result that you are asked to prove is false unless the univariate standard normal random variables are **independent** random variables.  See [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30205/6633) for a great description of how two normal random variables can fail to have a bivariate normal distribution.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thank you. I assume though that that is probably what the professor meant. Could you show me how the method with the Jacobians works assuming that that is so?

Comment: See [this document](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece313/fa2000/ppt/Lecture39.pdf) for how the Jacobian method applies to the special case of linear transformations of normal random variables.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Hmmh, I still don't really understand how it would work in this case. Could you please show me?