# Deriving the Bivariate Normal Distribution from Normal Distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, bivariate

If 
$X \sim N(0,{a^2})$, 
$Y \sim N(0,{b^2})$ and 
 $Corr(X,Y) = \rho $, 
 
then can we say that $(X,Y) \sim BVN(0,0,{a^2},{b^2};\rho )$?

If this is true, then can someone please tell me how can I proceed to show this mathematically?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that is not true. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pair-of-gaussian-random-variables-for-which-the-joint-d