# Jointed distribution of normal random variables

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, gaussian-process, joint-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

Given two models:

1. $Y_i = \alpha + \beta x_i + Z_i$, $i = 1, 2, 3, \dots , n$
2. $Y_i = A + B x_i + Z_i$, $i = 1, 2, 3, \dots , n$

where,  $\alpha$, $\beta$, $x_i$ are fixed and $A$ , $B$, $Z_i$'s are independent normally distributed random variables with mean zero and variance $\sigma_A^2$, $\sigma_B^2$, $\sigma^2$ respectively.

Is it possible to show that the vector $\mathbf{y} = (Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, \dots, Y_n)'$ is distributed as a multivariate normal?

There is a [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pair-of-gaussian-random-variables-for-which-the-joint-d) demonstrated that the joint distribution of a pair of Gaussian random variables are not necessary a bivariate normal. But how about the models stated above? And under what conditions, can lead the joint distribution of two normal random variables to be a bivariate normal?

Thanks!

---

The problems are solved now. Thanks @eric_kernfeld.

Since $A$ , $B$, $Z_i$'s are independent, $\mathbf{m} = (A, B, Z_1, Z_2, \dots, Z_n)' \sim N_{n+2}(\mathbf{0}_{n+2}, \Sigma_{n+2})$

$$
\Sigma 
= \left(\begin{matrix} 
\sigma_A^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & \sigma_B^2 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sigma^2 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \sigma^2 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & \sigma^2
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Property of multivariate normal distribution:

For any $\mathbf{x}_p \sim N_p(\mathbf{\mu}_p, \Sigma_p)$, constant vector $\mathbf{c}$ of length $k$ and $k \times p$ constant matrix $F$,

$$
\mathbf{c} + F\mathbf{x}_p \sim N_k(\mathbf{c} + F \mathbf{\mu}_p, F \Sigma_p F') \dots \dots (1)
$$

We can just find a vector $\mathbf{c}$ and matrix $F$ s.t. $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{c} + F \mathbf{m}$ and claim $\mathbf{y}$ are also multivariate normal.

Denote $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2,  \dots,  x_n)'$, $\mathbf{1}_n$ and $\mathbf{0}_n$ are vectors of $1$'s and $0$'s respectively with length $n$.

- For model 1,

$$
\mathbf{c} = \alpha 1_n + \beta \mathbf{x}
\quad , \quad
F = \left(\begin{matrix} \mathbf{0}_n & \mathbf{0}_n & I_n \end{matrix}\right)
$$

$$
\mathbf{c} + F \mathbf{m}
= \left(\begin{matrix}
\alpha + \beta x_1 + Z_1 \\
\vdots \\
\alpha + \beta x_n + Z_n
\end{matrix}\right)
= \mathbf{y}
$$

- For model 2, 
  $$
  \mathbf{c} = \mathbf{0}_{n}
  \quad , \quad 
  F = \left(\begin{matrix} \mathbf{1}_{n} & \mathbf{x} & I_n \end{matrix}\right)
  $$

$$
\mathbf{c} + F \mathbf{m}
= \left(\begin{matrix}
A + x_1 B + Z_1 \\
\vdots \\
A + x_n B + Z_n
\end{matrix}\right)
= \mathbf{y}
$$

Since $\mathbf{m}$ follows a multivariate normal distribution, $\mathbf{c}$ and $F$ are both fixed, using property $(1)$ we can claim that $\mathbf{y}$ is also multivariate normal in both model.

Comment: Independent normal random variables _do_ enjoy a bivariate (more generally, multivariate) normal distribution. The covariance matrix is a diagonal matrix in this case. It is a foul canard (apparently believed ti be true by about 30% of the readership of this site) that independent normal random variables cannot be called jointly normal random variables. _Nowhere_ in the definition is the covariance matrix _required_ to have nonzero off-diagonal entries. In short, there is nothing to _show_ or prove if you want to say that $\mathbf Y$ has a multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: In your displayed $\Sigma$ matrix, the entries on the first two lines should be $\sigma_A^2$ and $\sigma_B^2$, not $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$. Also, could you not have picked **any** other symbol than  $B$ for the transformation matrix seeing as how you already used $B$ in $Y_i = A + B x_i + Z_i$??

Comment: @DilipSarwate I have corrected the mistakes and change some symbols to make my steps less confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be answered using the following theorems:

1. N independent normal random variables are always jointly normal due to their independence.
2. Any affine (linear plus a fixed shift) function of a jointly normal random vector is still a multivariate normal. This comes with one caveat: if you multiply by zero or by a matrix $M$ where $M^T$ does not have full column rank, some people will call that normal (or "degenerate Gaussian") and some will not. The density of a degenerate Gaussian cannot be calculated naively: the determinant in the denominator would be zero.

To get started applying these to your second example, my "N" is your n + 2, because it must capture the Z's and A and B.

Comment: I have added the steps. Would you mind checking it? Thanks!

Comment: The basic idea is correct, but heed the comments from @DilipSarwate to clean things up.