# Is it possible to obtain joint PDF of set of variables given marginal PDF of each variable?

Tags: density-function, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

Say $f(X_1)$, $f(X_2)$, $f(X_3)$, $f(X_4)$ are the empirical marginal PDFs of random variables $X_1$, $X_2$ , $X_3$, $X_4$. Also given is correlation between each pair of variables $X_1$, $X_2$ , $X_3$, $X_4$. 
Is it possible to obtain the empirical joint PDF of $f(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4)$?

Comment: How do you define "empirical marginal PDFs";

Comment: @JohnK I obtained empirical PDFs from an experiment that I conducted

Comment: not without additional assumptions (eg. multi-variate normality would be sufficient).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, no.

In fact, even if the marginals are normally distributed, the joint distribution could be quite interesting.  Here is an one example: [Is it possible to have a pair of Gaussian random variables for which the joint distribution is not Gaussian?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pair-of-gaussian-random-variables-for-which-the-joint-d).

Comment: @Vimal the marginals of individual variables are definitely not normally distributed, I think it looks somewhat Gamma distributed.