# Normality of two variables jointly

Tags: normality-assumption, multivariate-normal-distribution, bivariate

Can someone explain me what the relation is between bivariate normal distribution and dependence and independence of two variables? When i search for this topic i get answer in dependence and independence of two variables :(

Answer (score 4):

If you know that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly a bivariate normal distribution then $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if they are uncorrelated.

However, the above statement is contingent on $X$ and $Y$ having a bivariate normal distribution. If all we know are the following facts:

1. The marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed.
2. The variables are uncorrelated.

Then it is possible to construct [examples where the variables are not independent of each other.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30205/919) (Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent for an example.)

Comment: +1  This was very well done and exactly what I would have said.

Comment: @whuber The link to cardinal's beautiful answer that you inserted via your edit might not be completely relevant here since, to the best of my belief, _none_ of the 6 examples in cardinal's answer has _uncorrelated but independent_ marginally normal random variables; they are all instances of marginally normal but not jointly normal random variables