# Operations with joint multivariate normal vectors

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, joint-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

Assuming $$ X\sim N_2(\mu_1, \sigma_1)$$ and $$Y \sim N_2(\mu_2, \sigma_2) $$

Would the joint distribution of

\begin{bmatrix}
X -Y \\
X+Y
\end{bmatrix}

be 4 dimensional? It would be multivariate normal too because it is the joint of 2 Multivariate normal vectors, correct?

Comment: what do you mean  "4 dimensional"?

Answer (score 3):

No. Unless your notation is misleading, $X$ and $Y$ are univariate.

Consequently each of $D=X-Y$ and $S=X+Y$ are univariate.

A vector made of those two random variables $[D,S]^\top$ is bivariate.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many incorrect notions in your assertions. Regardless of whether $X$ and $Y$ are multivariate normal or univariate normal random variables, $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are *not necessarily* normal random variables (multivariate or univariate as the case may be). If

- $X$ and $Y$ are $n$-variate normal random variables ($n \geq 1$)

*and*

- $\left[\begin{array}{c}X\\Y\end{array}\right]$ is a $2n$-variate normal random variable,

*then* $\left[\begin{array}{c}X+Y\\X-Y\end{array}\right]$ is a $2n$-variate normal random variable. Notice that $\left[\begin{array}{c}X+Y\\X-Y\end{array}\right]$ is a *linear* transformation of $\left[\begin{array}{c}X\\Y\end{array}\right]$, and it is a defining property of multivariate normality that linear transformations of multivariate normal random variables result in multivariate normal random variables. To forestall the inevitable question "Didn't I say that $X$ and $Y$ are multivariate normal and doesn't that automatically mean that $\left[\begin{array}{c}X\\Y\end{array}\right]$ is also multivariate normal?", note that
$$\left[\begin{array}{c}X\\Y\end{array}\right] 2n\text{-variate normal} \implies X, Y ~ n\text{-variate normal}$$
but the reverse implication is not true:
$$\require{cancel}X, Y ~ n\text{-variate normal} \cancel{\implies} \left[\begin{array}{c}X\\Y\end{array}\right] 2n\text{-variate normal}$$ Many counterexamples for the alleged reverse implication can be found in *[this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30205/6633)* by Moderator cardinal to the question [Is it possible to have a pair of Gaussian random variables for which the joint distribution is not Gaussian?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30159/6633)