# Sum of correlated normal distributions, difference between jointly distributed and not jointly distributed

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, joint-distribution

Lets say I simulate $X,Y$ and $Z$ from 3 standard normal distributions with pairwise correlations of 0.5, then I calculate the sum $X+Y-Z$. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Correlated_random_variables, since $X,Y,Z$ are **jointly** normally distributed, it seems the sum will be another normally distributed random variable with $\mu = 0$ and

$$ \sigma = \sqrt{ \sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2 + \sigma_Z^2 + 2\sigma_{XY} - 2\sigma_{XZ} - 2\sigma_{YZ} } $$

If, alternatively, $X,Y$ and $Z$ have the same correlation but are **not** jointly distributed, how does the distribution of $X+Y-Z$ change?

Furthermore, how would I even go about simulating $X,Y,Z$ with pairwise correlations of 0.5 that are **not** jointly distributed?

Comment: What you claim is the standard deviation of $X+Y-Z$ is wrong; two $+$ signs should be $-$ signs. So either you didn't correctly copy what Wikipedia says is the standard deviation of $X+Y-Z$ or you copied correctly and it is the Wikipedia page that has typographic errors in it. Which is it?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30205/919 for a great discussion of the central question about Normal variables that are not jointly Normal.

Answer (score 1):

Jointly normal RVs have a known form, but others don't. So, if a pair or triple of RVs are not jointly distributed, you **have** to know how they're connected to each other, which is specified via their specific joint distribution. For example, the following figure in this [wiki](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent) page shows two different non-normal joint distributions' scatter plots (that have normal marginals):

[image]

Once you have the joint distribution and how the variables are related, your sampling strategy will depend on it.