# Is a pair of two conditional gaussian distribution imply a joint gaussian distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, joint-distribution, conditional

Suppose $x,y$ are two random variables, if $p(x|y)$ is normal distribution, and $p(y|x)$ is also normal distribution, can we say that $p(x,y)$ is also joint normal distribution?

I know that two normal random variable does not imply joint normal distribution as in：
[Is it possible to have a pair of Gaussian random variables for which the joint distribution is not Gaussian?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pair-of-gaussian-random-variables-for-which-the-joint-d/190078#190078)

Comment: as i posted, my friend give an example as follows:
f(x,y) = b*exp(-a*x^2y^2)

Comment: By "$p(x\mid y)$ is a normal distribution" do you mean *the same* distribution for all $y$? Or do you allow the parameters to vary with $y$?

Comment: It isn't clear that the example in the comment is a density at all!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **NO**

The example you proposed in a comment do not work, due to the ,to me surprising,  fact that
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2 y^2} \; dx\; dy $$
do not converge, that is , it is $\infty$.

But there are many examples of bivariate densities with normal marginals, but that is not jointly normal. I will just give one such example. Define
$$ f(x,y)= C e^{-[x^2+y^2 + 2xy(x+y+x y)]} $$
for $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Numerical integration gives $C\approx 1/4.290147838$.  Since $x$ and $y$ play symmetrical roles it is enough to look at one of the conditionals. Let us first find the marginal of $Y$, which is (with the help of maple)
$$ g(y) = C \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\, {\mathrm e}^{-\frac{y^{2} \left(y^{2}+2 y +1\right)}{2 y^{2}+2 y +1}}}{\sqrt{2 y^{2}+2 y +1}}$$ giving rise to the conditional
$$ f(x \mid y) = \frac{{\mathrm e}^{-x^{2}-y^{2}-2 x y \left(x y +x +y \right)} \sqrt{2 y^{2}+2 y +1}}{\sqrt{\pi}\, {\mathrm e}^{-\frac{y^{2} \left(y^{2}+2 y +1\right)}{2 y^{2}+2 y +1}}}
$$ which indeed is a normal density, with expectation and variance which is a function of $y$.

There is a complete monograph dedicated to this subject: [Conditional Specification of Statistical Models](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97592)  by  Barry C. Arnold, Enrique Castillo, and José María Sarabia.