# When do marginal/conditionally normals imply joint normal?

Tags: normal-distribution, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution, conditional-distribution

I know that marginal normals do not imply joint normal, as some examples in [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pair-of-gaussian-random-variables-for-which-the-joint-d) gives. However, but I don't know of any theorems that talk about conditions under which marginal normals can imply normals. The solution in [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/572589/when-does-marginal-normal-indicates-joint-normal) is not satisfying (they only give a necessary condition).

In summary, I have two questions

1. Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are random vectors, each follows a (different) normal distribution. What are the conditions for $(X_1, X_2)^T$ to be normal? Does this only require a positive definite covariance matrix?
2. Suppose $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are univariate RVs and the conditionals $X_i|X_{-i}$ are normals for all $i$ where $X_{-i}$ denotes the vector $X = (X_1, ..., X_n)^T$ without $X_i$. Under which conditions will $X$ be normal?

Comment: A partial answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464827/is-a-pair-of-two-conditional-gaussian-distribution-imply-a-joint-gaussian-distri