# Distribution in simple regressions without intercept

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, regression-coefficients

how can I find the distribution of Yi = β1Xi + εi, when we know Xi is normally distributed and mean and standard deviation are unknown and εi is normally distributed with (0,1)? Can we assume it is also normally distrubuted?

Comment: Linear combination of normally distributed random variables I think is also normally distributed.

Comment: @Fiodor Only when you also assume all the variables have a multivariate normal distribution.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159.

Comment: @whuber Really englihting post! So, as I understand it $Y_{i}$ could be assumed normal if we it already holds that $(b_{1}X_{i},\epsilon_{i})$ is multivariate normal, based on the second anwser of the post?

Comment: @Fiodor1234 Yes, that's right.  And since we usually assume all $\varepsilon_i$ are independent of all $X_j,$ that implies the entire collection of $X_j$ and $\varepsilon_i$ have a multivariate Normal distribution when the $X_j$ are multivariate Normal and the $\varepsilon_i$ are multivariate Normal.