# Marginal and joint distributions of normal and student's

Tags: normal-distribution, joint-distribution, t-distribution, marginal-distribution

Is there an equivalence between two normal (student's) distributions. in the sense that, if my two variables (X,Y) are normal (student's) then their joint distribution is also normal (student's). I would be glad also if someone can direct me towards the right literature on it.

Comment: This is incorrect, if two marginals are Normal (Student), the joint is not necessarily Normal (Student).

Comment: See e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30159/7224