# Sign of product of standard normal random variables

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution

The question is mainly in the title:

> Given two standard normal random variables with correlation $\rho$, what is the distribution of sign of their product?

I understand that when $\rho=0$, we have two iid standard normal random variables and therefore, they take positive and negative values independently with probability $\frac12$.

But I don't know what to do if $\rho\ne0$. We can take $\rho>0$ without loss of generality (because if $X$ and $Y$ are std normal with correlation $\rho$, then $-X$ and $Y$ are std normal with correlation $-\rho$). But I could not proceed further.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As long as $(X,Y)$ is standard bivariate normal with correlation $\rho$, the probability that $XY$ is positive or negative can be found using the [well-known result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/255368/321264) for the positive quadrant probability $$P(X>0,Y>0)=\frac14+\frac1{2\pi}\sin^{-1}\rho \tag{1}$$

(This is likely discussed here before but I cannot quite find the question.)

You have

\begin{align}
P(XY>0)&=P(X>0,Y>0)+P(X<0,Y<0)
\\&=P(X>0,Y>0)+P(-X>0,-Y>0)
\end{align}

Because $(-X,-Y)$ has the same distribution as $(X,Y)$, this probability is just $$P(XY>0)=2P(X>0,Y>0)$$

Similarly,

\begin{align}
P(XY<0)&=P(X>0,Y<0)+P(X<0,Y>0)
\\&=P(X>0,-Y>0)+P(-X>0,Y>0)
\end{align}

Again, $(X,-Y)$ and $(-X,Y)$ have the same distribution, so

$$P(XY<0)=2P(X>0,-Y>0)$$

And since $(X,-Y)$ is bivariate normal with correlation $-\rho$, we have from $(1)$ that

$$P(X>0,-Y>0)=\frac14-\frac1{2\pi}\sin^{-1}\rho$$

Comment: The initial formula follows immediately from the analysis and illustrations at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71303/919.  The first quadrant corresponds to the sector $X^\prime \gt 0, Y^\prime \gt -\rho/\sqrt{1-\rho}^2$ where $(X^\prime,Y^\prime)$ has a standard Normal distribution.  Because the latter is rotationally symmetric, the chance of this sector is simply its angle divided by $2\pi.$  For positive $\rho$ this sector consists of the entire first quadrant plus the wedge $X\gt 0, -\rho/\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\lt Y \le 0,$ whose angle (by elementary geometry) is $\sin^{-1}\rho.$

Comment: There are equivalent formulas, btw.  One of them is that the expectation of $\operatorname{sgn}(XY)$ equals $2\arctan(\rho/\sqrt{1-\rho^2})/\pi.$  (Of interest is the appearance of the slope $\rho/\sqrt{1-\rho^2}$ of the boundary line, expressed as an angle.)  I believe this form of the result has appeared elsewhere on CV.

Comment: @whuber's first comment is also nicely illustrated in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1688568/321264) answer on Math.SE.

Answer (score 9):

Consider $X,Y\sim N(0,1)$ with correlation $\rho$. Then ([Nadarajah & Pogány, 2016](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.crma.2015.10.019); [Gaunt, 2018](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.03981.pdf)) their product is variance-gamma distributed:
$$ XY \sim \text{VG}(1,\rho,\sqrt{1-\rho^2},0). $$

Its PDF is
$$ f_{XY}(x) = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left(\frac{\rho x}{1-\rho^2}\right) K_0\left(\frac{|x|}{1-\rho^2}\right), $$
where $K_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind of order $0$.

Thus
$$ P(\text{sign}(XY) = -1) = \int_{-\infty}^0 f_{XY}(x)\,dx. $$

You may be able to evaluate this using your favorite computer algebra system. Unfortunately, [this exceeds the standard computation time for WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%28pi*sqrt%281-rho%5E2%29%29+*+exp%28rho*x%2F%281-rho%5E2%29%29*BesselK%280%2Cabs%28x%29%2F%281-rho%5E2%29%29+from+-infinity+to+0). [COOLSerdash notes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/547972/sign-of-product-of-standard-normal-random-variables/547976#comment1006414_547976) that the integral evaluates to a nice round $\frac{\arccos\rho}{\pi}$.

Alternatively, you could map the above parameterization to the one employed in the [`VarianceGamma` package for R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VarianceGamma/) and use the functions in there, if all you are interested in is numerical results.

Comment: The integral evaluates to $\arccos{(\rho)}/\pi$.

Comment: @COOLSerdash: nice! Thank you!

Comment: But you don't need the pdf of $XY$ to find this probability assuming $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal.

Comment: Many Thanks !!!

Answer (score 5):

The correlation alone is not enough to be able to derive the probability distribution for the sign.

See the example below for a case where $\rho = 2/\pi$ and the sign of $XY$ is always positive.

[image: example]

Comment: Normality is given in the question.

Comment: @Martund The variables $x$ and $y$ are following a standard normal distribution here.

Comment: It is impossible. You claim that product of two distinct standard normal random variables takes positive values with probability $1$???!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Martund I created the pairs of variables $X_i, Y_i$ from the answer in the following way. Let $X_i \sim N(0,1)$, let $Z_i \sim N(0,1)$ and let $Y_i = \text{abs}(Z_i) \times \text{sign}(X_i)$. Then $X_i$ and $Y_i$ each follow a standard normal distribution. Of course, they won't be independent and that is how you get that their product is always positive.

Comment: In the same way: If $\rho = 0$, then this does not need to mean that the variables are independent. For $\rho = 0$ you can also have different probabilities for the sign of the product $XY$.

Comment: Martund, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30205/919.  It will erase all the exclamation points in your comment.

Comment: Thank You @whuber, I got the point now..