# Contour lines for multivariate Laplace distribution

Tags: multivariate-distribution, laplace-distribution, elliptical-distribution

In the p-variate normal distribution ($\mathbf{N_p(\mu,\Sigma)}$),  the solid ellipsoid of **x** values satisfying

$(\mathbf{x-\mu)'\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\mu)}\leq \chi^2_p(\alpha)$

has probability $1-\alpha$ , where $\chi^2_p(\alpha)$ is the upper
$(100\alpha)$th percentile of a chi-square distribution with p degrees of freedom.

Is there a similar result for the Multivariate Laplace (symmetric) distribution? That is, which ellipsoid has probability $1-\alpha$ in the Multivariate Laplace case?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! In the case of a multivariate normal distribution, there is a standard definition. I do not know of a standard definition of a multivariate Laplace distribution. Is there one? How the marginal distributions relates to each other will be critical to creating the joint distribution. For instance, comments like [these](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30205/247274) could be written about Laplace margins instead of Gaussian.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I found a similar result for the multivariate t distribution. I saw drawings of the contours of a bivariate laplace, but it was not explained how the contours were made. If there is a way to get an estimate of such ellipsoids using R, it would be very helpful!

Comment: How would you make contour lines of any other multivariable function?

Comment: I'm interested in elliptical distributions, whose contours are ellipsoids. For example, for p-variate t the contours are given by: (x - \mu)' \Sigma^-1 (x - \mu) < p F(\alpha, p, v).
Where F(\alpha, p, v) is the upper (100α)th percentile of the F distribution and v is the degrees of freedom.

Comment: What happens when you plot the contour lines of a multivariate Laplace, such as independent margins?

Comment: I don't know how to plot contour lines, but I think if they are independent and identically distributed we will have circles.

Comment: There is an analogous result: because this is an elliptic distribution, the contours are also ellipsoids.  Instead of a chi-squared distribution governing the radial variable, though, the distribution has a density proportional to a monomial times a Bessel K function.  Unless you are using a powerful symbolic platform like *Mathematica,* you will likely need to find the ellipsoid through numeric integration and a root finder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know of any references that mention this topic?