# If $(X,Y,Z,\theta_1,\theta_2)$ $\sim \mathcal N_5(\mu,\Sigma)$, what is $\text{Var}[X+Y+Z|\theta_1,\theta_2]$?

Tags: self-study, variance, conditional-probability, covariance, multivariate-normal-distribution

How to compute the conditional variance of a sum of three normally distributed random variables given two other random variables? Assume pairwise correlations exist and the following joint distributions:

$X\sim \mathcal N(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$;
$Y\sim \mathcal N(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y^2)$;
$Z\sim \mathcal N(\mu_Z,\sigma_Z^2)$;
$\theta_1\sim \mathcal N(\mu_{\theta_1},\sigma_{\theta_1}^2)$;
$\theta_2\sim \mathcal N(\mu_{\theta_2},\sigma_{\theta_2}^2)$;

The multidimensional linear projection theorem can be directly applied to find the conditional mean and variance of random variable/partition of random variables A given random variable/partition of random variables B, but what if A is a combination of three random variables? **I am new to the community, so please do not close the question without detailing what else is needed. Thanks.**

Comment: To ask a good question, do not miss specifying the distributions of r.v.s appeared in the expression of your interest.  For example, what are the distribution of $\theta_i$?  Are $(X, Y, Z, \theta_1, \theta_2)$ jointly normal?  Also, if all "5 random variables have different $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$", it is better to use a different notation instead of "$\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$".  Based on your second paragraph, I think your question can be better framed as "If $(X, Y, Z, \theta_1, \theta_2) \sim N_5(\mathbf{\mu}, \Sigma)$, what is $\operatorname{Var}(X + Y + Z | \theta_1, \theta_2)$?"

Comment: Thank you for the edits.  However, the updated question is still not clear enough to state the "joint distribution" of these 5 r.v.s.  Do you know the well-known result that "marginal normality" does not imply "joint normality"?  See [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pair-of-gaussian-random-variables-for-which-the-joint-d).  The joint normality is essential to derive a closed-form of the conditional variance of your interest.  Without it (or with the info you provided so far), it is undetermined.

Comment: To clarify, the title looks good.  It is the question body that needs to be further updated.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=conditional+normal+distribution

Comment: I significantly edited the body of my question - sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: @anonymous That's not a good practice (in particular after an answer to your original question has been posted).  If you have a completely different question, just post a new one.

Comment: I totally agree. I am sorry again for any inconvenience. Lesson learned. I will post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Denote $(X, Y, Z)$ and $(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ by $X_1$ and $X_2$, and partition the mean vector $\mu$ and the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ accordingly to as follows:
\begin{align*}
\mu = \begin{bmatrix} \mu_1 \\ \mu_2 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} \\ \Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22}
\end{bmatrix}. 
\end{align*}
Then by the [conditional distribution property](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/612101/how-to-apply-the-linear-projection-theorem-in-three-dimensions) of the multivariate normal distribution, the conditional variance of $X_1$ given $X_2$ is $\bar{\Sigma} = \Sigma_{11} - \Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\Sigma_{21}$ (this result is also cited in another question [by yourself](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/612101/how-to-apply-the-linear-projection-theorem-in-three-dimensions), though in a more verbose way).  Now write $X + Y + Z = e'X_1$, where $e = (1, 1, 1)'$.  [It then follows that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Which_matrices_are_covariance_matrices?):
\begin{align}
 & \operatorname{Var}(X + Y + Z|\theta_1, \theta_2) \\
=& \operatorname{Var}(e'X_1|X_2) \\
=& e'\operatorname{Var}(X_1|X_2)e \\
=& e'\bar{\Sigma}e. 
\end{align}
Of course, you can proceed to expand $e'\bar{\Sigma}e$ by finishing tedious matrix operations to express the final result in terms of $\sigma_X^2, \ldots, \sigma_{\theta_2}^2$ and their pairwise correlations $\rho_{ij}$. To me, I think $e'\bar{\Sigma}e$ is a more succinct and equally clear result, so I will be satisfied to stop here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I significantly edited the body of my question - sorry for any inconvenience caused.