# Join distribution of independent random variables that aren't conditionally independent

Tags: distributions, independence, joint-distribution, conditional-independence

I am asked to give an example for a joint distribution of three random variables, $U$, $V$ and $W$, where $U$ and $V$ are (unconditionally) independent but are NOT conditionally independent given $W$.

It is also known that:

- $U$ and $V$ are normally distributed with a mean of $2$ and a variance of $2$ (that is, $U \sim N(2, 2)$ and $V \sim N(2, 2)$)
- $W$ is a coin toss and has two possible values

I understand the possibility of two independent variables becoming conditionally dependent on a third variable (as well explained on multiple answers of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1900375/is-it-possible-that-two-independent-variables-become-dependent-conditioning-on-a) for example), but not sure how it applies given the above requirements and would appreciate assistance.

Comment: For inspiration, stare at the upper right image at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30205/919 for a few seconds.  If you would like another hint, let $W$ be heads if and only if $(U-2)(V-2)$ is positive.